# Play form parameters help decipher compile error

Tags: scala, view, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Controller defined like this:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.Task
import play.api.data.Form

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    // Compiler error on Form
    Ok(views.html.index(List[Task](), Form("label" -> "This is a label")))  
  }

  def tasks = TODO

  def newTask = TODO

  def deleteTask(id: Long) = TODO

}
```

Then I have defined a View:

```
@(tasks: List[Task], taskForm: Form[String])

@import helper._

@main("Todo list") {

  <h1>@tasks.size task(s)</h1>

  <ul>
    @tasks.map { task =>
      <li>
        @task.label

        @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
          <input type="submit" value="Delete">
        }
      </li>
    }
  </ul> 

}
```

This gives the following compiler error:

> overloaded method value apply with alternatives:   [T](mapping:
>   (String, play.api.data.Mapping[T]))play.api.data.Form[T] 
>   [T](mapping: play.api.data.Mapping[T])play.api.data.Form[T]  cannot be
>   applied to ((java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String))    Application.scala   /todolist/app/controllers   line
>   11    Scala Problem

Can you help me decipher the compilers output.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: you are trying to apply a `(String, String)` parameter to a method taking `(String, Mapping[T])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem: `Form("label" -> "This is a label")`. You are trying to call method `Form.apply(p: (String, String))` and there is no such method in [`Form`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Form.scala) object.